# Create XLS or CSV from file names in folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, filenames

I have a few hundred files in a folder on a Windows 7 machine. Is there a way to generate an XLS, or CSV file from the file names in the folder?

A text file is fine as well; Just looking for any method to automatically extract the file names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One very quick and dirty way is the command prompt. Simply open one, navigate to your folder and funnel the result into a text file using this command:

```
dir > filenames.txt
```

You will have to do some cleaning up, but as I said "quick and dirty". :-)
If you only want certain objects you can of course limit the output of your 'dir' command.

The option Cybertox mentioned might be a good idea:

> /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

Comment: `dir /b` would get you just the filenames

Comment: `dir /b` - all files ... except hidden files. If you want those, include `/a`. For more options try `dir /?`

Answer (score 28):

You can use PowerShell to create an actual CSV file:

`dir | Export-Csv MyFileList.csv`

Comment: It puts the result in the folder. I would then open it in VS Code using the Excel Viewer extension (this is a much lighter weight way to view Excel and CSV).

Comment: Thanks, found this useful. Please all, be aware that this added MyFileList to the file list!

Answer (score 6):

This used to work on older Windows versions and gave the full path of all files:

```
dir /s /b > list.txt
```

Comment: Assuming you don't want the directory names of the directories each directory contains, use: dir /s /b /a-d > list.txt

Answer (score 3):

If you also want the metadata (owner, size, modified date), see [PowerShell command to write directory to CSV](http://heuristicandrew.blogspot.com/2014/09/write-directory-listing-to-csv-in.html) for a one-liner

Powershell code from source by Andrew Z.

```
powershell "Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp3 -Recurse E:\media\music\ | ForEach-Object {$_ | add-member -name "Owner" -membertype noteproperty -value (get-acl $_.fullname).owner -passthru} | Sort-Object Length -Descending | Select FullName,Name,Length,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Owner | Export-Csv -Force -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\mpeg-3.csv"
```

This is slightly changed to fufill the criteria drewdqueue needed, which was all MP3 files in descending order or size and Name as a seperate entry.